# https of subdomain redirects to main domain - certbot on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

I am running nginx and would like to ask you help in explaining how to set up a correct configuration. Im not expert of server maintenance and would like to avoid to misconfigure the running sites.

Below an extract of nginx configuration (the part I think relevant) :

```
server {

    server_name www.sub.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://sub.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 7000;
    server_name example.com;
...

    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nifty.works/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nifty.works/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

and a proxy server like:


# Virtualhost/server configuration
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name sub.example.com;

..

}
```

I am using certbot, and I remember I tried to set up automatically the certificate, but had an issue, an I succeded to install correctly an SSL certificate for the main site, if I recall well, using a wildcard certificate.

Certificate expired yesterday, I renewed it helping myself with:

```
certbot renewal
```

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx

and can see it works OK with the main site.

However, with sub sites, `https://sub.example.com` points will display the site of the main `https://example.com` (note, it is **not** a redirect), while with **http** `http://sub.example.com` displays the correct site.

With `sudo certbot certonly --nginx` I can see the list of subdomains to activate https for.

Before tampering, I would like to ask you:

Can you can help to brief me out in setting up a correct  configuration for SSL also for subdomains?

Please note that all subdomains makes use of APIs (mostly GET, a few POST) : I am concerned about breaking the site (backend is in flask python, and possibly wish to avoid to set up users credentials - it is just an open site, with a few share plugins from socials).

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely the fault of the NGINX configuration, and it is behaving As Configured by certbot / yourself.

When an NGINX `server` section listens on a port, if it is the *only* service listening on that port it will become the **default server block** to match on that port.  This is By Design.

You will need a *separate* section in your configuration for your subdomain with a valid HTTPS configuration and certificate on it to make requests to https://sub.example.com/ to go to the correct docroot.

Example configuration of this (except both server blocks serve HTTP and HTTPS without needing to expand the number of server configurations):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # ... other config here
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name sub.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/sub.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/sub.example.com.key;

    root /var/www/sub.example.com;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    # other configuration for site here

}
```

When you request `https://sub.example.com`, it matches the configuration for the second site on HTTP and HTTPS because *both* HTTP and HTTPS listeners are configured for that server block.  If you request `https://foo.example.com` however, it will fall back to the server with the default_server block for the 443 listener, which serves `example.com` and not the subdomain.

Essentially, you need to have a custom configuration that serves a certbot certificate for your subdomain on port 443 in order to work.  Unfortunately, you cannot use the `certbot` `nginx` installer to do this, and will need to configure certbot to use standalone/webroot mode for your certificates and then configure NGINX yourself by hand for the proper paths to SSL certificates (and the .well-known handshakes that go on as well).

Certbot config on how to use standalone / webroot mode is here:  https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot

You will need to utilize this method to configure two separate SSL docroots/domains per your nginx configuration and then configure your NGINX ssl_certificate paths to point at the Lets Encrypt paths on-disk.  (This process is too long to fit into a single answer, but if you wish I can create a chat room to walk you through the process)

Comment: wow, thank you very much @Thomas Ward for your offer to set up a chat room. I would appreciate that. If you don't mind, I will show you the nginx configurations I have and take the opportunity to also learn a bit of good practices. I have different subdomain sites, each listening to its own port (python flask), and need to route each port on the nginx side properly. So far I managed, I will appreciate to listen to some suggestions to improve handling operations.